# Testing PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing

I'm running the unit tests included in PHPUnit to verify my installation.

I get the same results running from the IDE and from the command line.

Says it can't find the Success class. But the IDE finds it with no problem in
C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\PHP\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\tests\_files
with all the rest of the support files.

I can't see any reason for it not to be found.

> "C:\Program Files\PHP\5.6\php.exe" C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/ide-phpunit.php --configuration C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\PHP\vendor\phpunit\phpunit.xml
>
> Testing started at 4:26 AM ...
>
> PHP Fatal error:  **Class 'Success' not found** in C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\PHP\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\tests\Extensions\RepeatedTestTest.php on line 23

PHP v 5.6

PHPUnit v 5.0.3

EDIT: The one change I made to the setup was adding a phpunit.xml to allow testing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="PHPUnit Test Suite">
        <directory>./php-code-coverage/tests/</directory>
        <directory>./php-file-iterator/tests/</directory>
        <directory>./php-text-template/tests/</directory>
        <directory>./php-timer/tests/</directory>
        <directory>./php-token-stream/tests/</directory>
        <directory>./phpunit/tests/</directory>
        <directory>./phpunit-mock-objects/tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: I tried 'composer dump', it didn't complain, but I can't tell that it did anything. The only reference I can find is 'composer dump-autoload' which doesn't look related.

Comment: dump-autoload updates the autoloader (the thing that enables you to use other files/classes without using `require` or `import`), which is likely what you wish to do.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to my lack of reputation.
What I usually do in this situation is to activate all PHP errors at the beginning of the main unit tests file:

```
// Activate all PHP type errors
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( "display_errors", "On" );
```

Since this shows every single warning and notice, this can help to find an `include` which is not working well in the command line context.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that when I get time to get back to testing this.  meanwhile, this is a useful tip for lots of issues. Thanks again.